# Calculating inductance of inductor that has ferrite core and a large air gap

Tags: inductor, inductance, ferrite, equation

I'm working on a coil on a PCB that will have a small ferrite core place in the center, with a large gap.

[image: Example]

I'm trying to come up with a decent equation to estimate the inductance of this inductor.  I've found good equations for solenoids and other shapes of inductors, but all of them assume a single "ideal" core with one permeability.

How should I represent this type of core so I can use existing equations to calculate my inductance?  Should I look to a different method to estimate inductance?

E.g. one thought I had was to calculate an "average" core permeability based on how much area is ferrite and how much is air, and then use this average to represent a single ideal core.  But I'm not sure if that would be correct.

Comment: if that is just a lump of ferrite, and not wrapped around your coils, you can pretty much ignore it. Your effective permebaility will be very close to e0.

Comment: what's going on in the other axis? Is that a ferrite pill or a 200mm ferrite rod?

Comment: You could also use equation for a "pancake coil" to get a reasonable estimate of inductance (without a core).